# Is "basis times square matrix" a new basis?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Suppose we have a vector space $V = (K, +, \cdot)$. Let $B$ be a basis for $V$. Now we take an arbitrary square matrix $S \neq 0$.

$BS$ is just a linear combination of $B$. Thus $BS$ should be a new basis. Am I right?

Comment: What is $K$. Is $K$ a field and you perhaps meant to write $K^n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a new basis  the matrix $S$ should have nonzero determinant.

Comment: So $BS$ is a new basis, because it is nothing more than a linear combination of a given basis?

Comment: yes, nontrivial(!)  linear combinatoin

Comment: When is a linear combination nontrivial?

Comment: See a definition in any linear algebra book

Answer (score 2):

Your question is open to several interpretations. (At least the [current revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1333605/3).) And we could write quite a lot about each of these interpretations.

You are using notation $BS$, which is (as far as I can say), most frequently use to denote the matrix product. But you also write that $B$ is a basis. Basis is not a matrix. So we could dismiss your questions as nonsensical.  Or we could try to look whether we can interpret it in a way in which it makes sense.

**Matrix interpretation:**

Let us assume that you are working with the vector space $V=F^n$ over a field $F$. Then the vectors of this vector space are $n$-tuples.

If we have some basis $\vec b_1,\dots,\vec b_n$, then we can put the vectors of this basis in a matrix $B$. Now it makes sense to make the product $BS$ of the two $n\times n$ matrices. And your question can be interpreted as the question whether the columns of the matrix $BS$ again for a basis of $F^n$. (I chose [column vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_vector) rather than [row vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_vector), since the wording of your question seems to indicate that you are used to working with column vectors.)

The notion of [invertible matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) is useful for this. If $B$ is a $n\times n$-matrix over a field $n$, then the following conditions are equivalent:

- The matrix $B$ is *invertible*, i.e., there exists a matrix $A$ such that $AB=BA=I$.
- Determinant of $B$ is non-zero, i.e., $\det B\ne0$.
- The matrix $B$ has full rank, i.e., $\operatorname{rank}(B)=n$.
- The rows of the matrix $B$ form a basis of $F^n$.
- The columns of the matrix $B$ form a basis of $F^n$.

You can find a few more equivalent condition in the Wikipedia article I linked above. With this in mind, your question can be understood as:

> When is the product of an invertible matrix $B$ and a square matrix $S$ again an invertible matrix.

The answer is that this is true if and only if $S$ is invertible. Indeed, we have 
$$S=B^{-1}(BS)$$
so $S$, as a product of two invertible matrices, is invertible.

You can find several posts on this site showing that product of invertible matrices is invertible (or some equivalent statement). For example:

- [Does the product of two invertible matrix remain invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220172/does-the-product-of-two-invertible-matrix-remain-invertible)
- [${\rm rank}(BA)={\rm rank}(B)$ if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801250/rm-rankba-rm-rankb-if-a-in-mathbbrn-times-n-is-invertible)
- [Prove that if a product$ AB$ of $n\times n$ matrices is invertible, so are the factors $A$ and $B$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446964/prove-that-if-a-product-ab-of-n-times-n-matrices-is-invertible-so-are-the-f)

**Linear combination of columns:**

From the formulation of your question it seems that you have noticed a useful observation about multiplication of matrices. Columns of the matrix $BS$ are linear combinations of the columns of $B$. And coefficients of these linear combinations are given by the entries of $S$. (Similar observation for rows is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31725/intuition-behind-matrix-multiplication/31734#31734).)

With this in mind we can make your question into a question which makes sense for every **finitely-dimensional** vector space $V$, not only $V=F^n$.

> Suppose $\vec b_1,\dots,\vec b_n$ is a basis of $V$. Let $S$ be an $n\times n$-matrix. Let us define vectors $\vec c_1,\dots,\vec c_n$ as
>   $$\vec c_k = \sum_{i=1}^n s_{ik} \vec b_k.$$
>   For which matrices $S$ is $\vec c_1,\dots,\vec c_n$ a basis?

If $V=F^n$, then this is precisely the question about matrices, since the vectors we described here are precisely the columns of the matrix $BS$. However, this formulation makes sense for any basis.

The answer to this question is again that this is true if and only if $S$ is invertible.

For more about this, you can have a look at matrix representing [change of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis).

**Linear combination of rows:**

We could ask similar question as above, but we could put vectors of the basis into row of a matrix. This does not change the answer. But in this case we can make a simple argument like this: We are basically asking whether the linear transformation $\vec x\mapsto \vec x S$ transforms a basis into a basis. (Since if we denote $\vec b_1,\dots,\vec b_n$ the rows of $B$, then the rows of $BS$ are $\vec b_1S,\dots,\vec b_nS$.)

The linear map $\vec x\mapsto \vec xS$ maps a basis to a basis if and only if it is a linear isomorphism. And equivalent condition is that $S$ is an invertible matrix.